# In a continuous form, can I have a combo box use a different query depending on a field or text box value within its own record?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox

Edit: for those wondering, it's apparently impossible to have the same combo box for two different records in a continuous form refer to two different queries to populate its list.

I have a continuous form that has maybe 5 records. There is a combo box, Laborer1, and would like the dropdown to be different for each form, depending on some other factors. I managed to put the exact query I want for each record's combo box as a text field within that record. What is the next step? All I can manage at this point is apply the query of one record to all combo boxes, but I want each combo box to use its "own" query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but there's a tradeoff: inactive records may have a value which doesn't fit within the current rowsource for the combobox. When that happens, you'll get a blank combobox, instead of having it show the current value. If you activate the record, the value will appear again, but it's not a fantastic user experience.

That said, one option would be to handle it in the `Form_Current` event. Since you're already storing the rowsource in a database field, the code for this is really short:

```
Private Sub Form_Current
  Laborer1.RowSource = ReferenceField.Value
  Laborer1.Requery 'I don't believe you need this, but you might.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, though my whole process of getting this to work seems a bit messy. Do you know if there might be a better way to accomplish different queries for comboboxes in continuous forms, or was Access not really meant to do this easily? Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's not meant to work like that. A continuous form is really meant to make it easy to have a repeating element, which implies that each instance would be the same. If you really dig into it, you'll find that most of the properties of the continuous form apply not to the active record, but to every record in the form. That makes what you want to do difficult to achieve without a messy workaround.

Comment: Oh wait! Whoops, I said it worked, but I was actually wrong. I did a proper test, and it seems to take the filter of whatever record has focus.

Comment: If by 'filter' you mean 'rowsource', then that's what I was trying to describe above. The combobox for every record will have the rowsource from whatever record currently has focus, which could potentially mean that some records don't show the current value at all if it's not in the rowsource.

Comment: Ah, I guess I wasn't 100% clear. I wanted the combo boxes for each record to be completely unlinked. So I guess this isn't possible for Access? Would the next best thing be to use conditional formatting to color invalid selections?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, either. :-) I did get what you wanted, but this is the best you can do in Access, for the reasons explained in my previous comments. It does work to allow a separate dropdown for each record, because the rowsource changes as you move between records, but it's a crummy user experience.

Comment: Conditional formatting won't work, I'm afraid, because it applies to the entire field, not individual items in the combobox.

Comment: Shucks, well I guess I could have conditional formatting color the selection after the fact. Not the most user-friendly, but at least they will get some sort of indication, rather than none. I never liked the idea of storing vba variables in my tables anyways. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer for continuous forms. When u click on combobox other combos turns blank but when u select everything looks normal.

I worked with my tables so sorry for a different example.. Anyway  I think It is an answer..

I have 2 combobox and when u select the country the city combo shows only the selected Country's Cities.

**This code is for Country Combo**

```
Private Sub Country_Change()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset


Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset
Set rsTable = dbs.OpenRecordset("Cities", dbOpenTable)

'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a saved query
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Cities WHERE Country='" + Country + "'", dbOpenDynaset)
'We created a recordset filtered and set it to city.recordset
Set city.Recordset = rsQuery
city.Requery
End Sub
```

And this 2 sub is for City Combo..

```
Private Sub City_Change()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset
Set rsTable = dbs.OpenRecordset("Cities", dbOpenTable)

'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a saved query
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Cities", dbOpenDynaset)

Set city.Recordset = rsQuery
'We created a recordset NOT filtered and set it to city.recordset and after that we focus on a different control to be sure that our city combobox work correctly
city.Requery
Kimlik.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub City_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset


Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset
Set rsTable = dbs.OpenRecordset("Cities", dbOpenTable)

'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a saved query
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Cities WHERE Country='" + Country + "'", dbOpenDynaset)
'We created a recordset filtered and set it to city.recordset
Set city.Recordset = rsQuery
city.Requery
End Sub
```

And here is [my Access file](http://www.ssmersin.somee.com/ExcellAccess/WorldCities.accdb)